# How does WP media uploader create the 3 different sized images, and how can I duplicate it

Tags: uploads, attachments, images

I have finally!! got this thing I've tried about 12 times to make and 12 different ways, but finally got it to work,... sort of.

I made a custom metabox for uploading and attaching images to posts, and it doesn't require you to use the horrible thickbox media uploader built into WP. I hate that thing. No, what I've done is just a group of inputs (title, description, file), which you can also duplicate, to add additional attachments if you want. So you fill in the fields, select an image to upload, and save draft or publish the post. Once there are attachments added to a post, the metabox will display the input fields, along with a preview image of the attached image for each attachment you added. The title and description fields are used to generate the file meta data, nothing is saved as the post_meta, that I know of. That's currently all that I have gotten working so far.

I need to make it so that when you save/publish a post, inturn upload/create the attachment files, it will create the three image sizes as the default wp uploader would, thumbnail, medium, large, and keeping the full size image too. If that's possible somehow. If not, I would like to otherwise use `add_image_size()` to create/define new custom sizes, and generate them that way instead, upon uploading.

I'm not sure which function is the most ideal to use in this case, maybe the `image_make_intermediate_size()` function would be better, or `wp_create_thumbnail()` or `wp_crop_image()`... who knows!!

I cannot figure out how to go about doing that, if I need to run the `wp_handle_upload()` function for each one, or maybe something involving the `wp_generate_attachment_metadata()` function. It's confusing to me since the 3 image sizes are to be associated as variants of the same attachment, and how to go about doing that.

I have scoured the web, read the source of every wp media/upload/image related file, and played with just about every function there is for the media upload stuff and cannot find how WP creates the 3 image sizes anywhere, or how to do it myself.

In wp-includes/media.php the `image_resize()` function looks like it would be best since it's exactly what it should be. I just can't figure out for the life of me what the hell I'm missing or have tried doing but did wrong to make the image thumbnails.

Here's my working function that does the `wp_handle_upload()` stuff and things, but it also needs to create the 100px thumb, and make a resize version of the image that is max-width like 500px, and saved as new files of the uploaded one.

```
function update_attachment(){
  global $post;

  wp_update_attachment_metadata( $post->ID, $_POST['a_image'] );

  if( !empty( $_FILES['a_image']['name'] )) { //New upload
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );

    $override['action'] = 'editpost';
    $url = wp_handle_upload( $_FILES['a_image'], $override );

    // $medium = image_make_intermediate_size( $uploaded_file['url'], 500, 400, true );
    // $thumb = = image_make_intermediate_size( $uploaded_file['url'], 100, 100, true );

    if ( isset( $file['error'] )) {
      return new WP_Error( 'upload_error', $file['error'] );
    }

    $array_type = wp_check_filetype
    $allowed_file_types = array('image/jpg','image/jpeg','image/gif','image/png');

    $name_parts = pathinfo( $name );
    $name = trim( substr( $name, 0, - ( 1 + strlen( $name_parts['extension'] )) ));

    $type = $file['type'];
    $file = $file['file'];
    $title = $_POST['a_title'] ? $_POST['a_title'] : $name;
    $content = $_POST['a_desc']

    $post_id = $post->ID;
    $attachment = array(
      'post_title' => $title,
      'post_type' => 'attachment',
      'post_content' => $content,
      'post_parent' => $post_id,
      'post_mime_type' => $type,
      'guid' => $url['url']
    );


    // Save the data
    $id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $_FILES['a_image'][ 'file' ]/*, $post_id - for post_thumbnails*/);

    if ( !is_wp_error( $id )) {
      $attach_meta = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $id, $uploaded_file['url'] );
      wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_meta );
    }
    update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'a_image', $uploaded_file['url'] );
  }
}
```

Anyone able to help me finally fix this so it works proper would be loved. I've spent so many ridiculous countless hours numerous different times trying to develop this thing and the documentation sucks, and there's not really any good posts anywhere on how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Check the comments on the various answers below and I think either I or @בניית אתרים or both of us are confused on what you need.

Comment: Has anyone solved this?? Having a similar problem, have been scowering the web for ages on this one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hi **@jaredwilli:**

Dude! Valiant effort, and nice work. All-in-all it could be a great addition to WordPress.

You were so close, but you had somewhere between 5 and 10 little failed assumptions or code that looks like you started it but didn't get back to it because it wasn't working.  I reworked your function only as much as I needed to correct it. The solution follows, and I'll leave the side-by-side comparison to your or someone less burned-out. :)

```
function update_attachment() {
  global $post;
  wp_update_attachment_metadata( $post->ID, $_POST['a_image'] );
  if( !empty( $_FILES['a_image']['name'] )) { //New upload
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );

    $override['action'] = 'editpost';
    $file = wp_handle_upload( $_FILES['a_image'], $override );

    if ( isset( $file['error'] )) {
      return new WP_Error( 'upload_error', $file['error'] );
    }

    $file_type = wp_check_filetype($_FILES['a_image']['name'], array(
      'jpg|jpeg' => 'image/jpeg',
      'gif' => 'image/gif',
      'png' => 'image/png',
    ));
    if ($file_type['type']) {
      $name_parts = pathinfo( $file['file'] );
      $name = $file['filename'];
      $type = $file['type'];
      $title = $_POST['a_title'] ? $_POST['a_title'] : $name;
      $content = $_POST['a_desc'];

      $post_id = $post->ID;
      $attachment = array(
        'post_title' => $title,
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_content' => $content,
        'post_parent' => $post_id,
        'post_mime_type' => $type,
        'guid' => $file['url'],
      );

      foreach( get_intermediate_image_sizes() as $s ) {
        $sizes[$s] = array( 'width' => '', 'height' => '', 'crop' => true );
        $sizes[$s]['width'] = get_option( "{$s}_size_w" ); // For default sizes set in options
        $sizes[$s]['height'] = get_option( "{$s}_size_h" ); // For default sizes set in options
        $sizes[$s]['crop'] = get_option( "{$s}_crop" ); // For default sizes set in options
      }

      $sizes = apply_filters( 'intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', $sizes );

      foreach( $sizes as $size => $size_data ) {
        $resized = image_make_intermediate_size( $file['file'], $size_data['width'], $size_data['height'], $size_data['crop'] );
        if ( $resized )
          $metadata['sizes'][$size] = $resized;
      }

      $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file['file'] /*, $post_id - for post_thumbnails*/);

      if ( !is_wp_error( $id )) {
        $attach_meta = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file['file'] );
        wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_meta );
      }
      update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'a_image', $file['url'] );
    }
  }
}
```

Hey, why not splurge and get yourself a copy of [PhpStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/)? You could have easily solved this yourself, you were sooo close, if you could have just traced through the code like I now can. If you do, don't waste your time on the very buggy [XDEBUG](http://www.xdebug.org/) and instead download [Zend Debugger](http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio/downloads).

P.S. This is my former answer. I posted this before I realized what exactly Jared was asking.  It is correct, but not related to his question. :)

---

I think what you are looking for is `add_image_size()`:

```
add_image_size( $size_id, $width, $height, $crop );
```

For example:

```
add_image_size('headshot', 130, 150);
add_image_size('large-headshot', 260, 300);
```

By setting this WordPress will create those sizes automatically.  What that what you needed?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, he is asking for the creation of the default media sizes.

Comment: Hmm. The function `wp_generate_attachment_metadata()` does that if `add_image_size()` is set. Maybe he just didn't try using `add_image_size()` to set the image sizes?

Comment: yea but, jaredwilli is saying that the default WordPress built-in sizes (large,medium,thumbnail) are no being created then surly the extra added sizes using add_image_size() wont be created either.

Comment: or maybe I'm not getting the question at all :)

Comment: @בניית אתרים - I'm getting confused now too. I think we need to wait to here clarification from @jaredwilli.

Comment: Back. I am trying to do either or. The default sizes are not being created like I would think they would be using the generate_attach_metadata function and if I were to try creating them using my own sizes with add_image_size, i am not sure how to do that. 
I assume just include the function with the needed params passed to it, and then after that what would need to be done to generate the images exactly, if anything?

Comment: I am not understanding why the wp_generate_attachment_metadata() is not generating the image sizes like it should. It has all the code needed to do it, and I am not using anything that would make it not work as it should so makes no sense to me.

Comment: @jaredwilli - You didn't provide a complete example of what you are doing; you only posted the one function. Can you post everything I'd need to test what you are doing, maybe on gist.github.com if it is a lot of code?  Without seeing it all I'm getting lost and my guess is I'm making an assumption that is wrong for your code, or you are doing something that violates an an assumption the WordPress code that I've not thought to consider.

Comment: Okay here's the rest of the code. Hopefully it works like it should, in order to make it usable for you to test and stuff I had to alter what I know works since it was for a custom post type, so I changed it to be added to the 'post' type.
https://gist.github.com/802465

Comment: If it does work, you will notice that there is an option to Add Another image, which you can use to attach multiple images with. Just incase that information turns out to be important to know.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel Not sure if you've looked at this yet. https://gist.github.com/802465

Comment: @jaredwilli - Yes I looked at it, that's the code I fixed 2 hours ago. See my updated answer. BTW, I notice in your example you gave me the "remove" doesn't work, but that's okay; it doesn't need to work for me.

Comment: Oh cool, I didnt realize you updated it 2 hours ago oops. I know the remove link didnt work, that wasnt a big deal, its an easy fix, although. It does lead to another issue altogether.

Comment: When the remove link was working, it removes the div that holds the input fields from the page, using jquery .remove() but, when you save the post, the removed attachment is still attached. I had it at one point working sort of, it would delete the image file from the attachment when clicking remove (not the entire div idk why) so you click remove, the preview image would disappear and there would no longer be an image file for it. Maybe worth posting as another question.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel Thanks!! That works perfectly!!! You have no idea how unbelievably insane this has made me. On numerous occasions, since last June. I have tried to make something that does this so many times and have always ALMOST gotten it to work. I've always been so close, and finally got it to upload images so I had to finish it once that was working.

Comment: @jaredwilli - Yeah, it was definitely be another post. Working with jQuery like that can be uber-tricky, or at least I've not attained guru status on it yet. :) BTW, lesson learned is, if possible, provide a self-contained example we can pull down and test and it will streamline this process greatly?

Comment: Now I just need to make the delete function work. I have done something like this, though not this.

$uploaded_image = (int) get_post_meta($post_id,'a_image', true);                            if(is_numeric($uploaded_image)){                    wp_delete_attachment($uploaded_image);
}
Oops, cant post code in comments,

Comment: I don't even see what you did that was different from any of the million different things I had to have tried at one point or another. It looked just like code I had written. What were the little failed assumptions you had fixed exactly?

Comment: @jaredwilli - I was going to list them but I had to make so many little changes I lost track. It was mostly at the top of the file;  it was also variables you created and didn't use (`$url`, `$allowed_file_types`) as well as variables that you used but didn't create (`$file`,`$images`,`$uploaded_file`), code that wasn't syntactically valid (`wp_check_filetype`), and assuming `$_FILES['a_image']['name']` contained a full path instead of just the base filename.

Comment: Oh, well like you had said, I was obviously in the middle of adding removing and changing things around, and quite a lot too. I had just added much of that stuff, and was undoing/redoing my changes alot trying to get things back to working and then changed to work with what i wanted to add. Anyways, thanks for your help, i've downloaded PhpStorm, again, finally. I hate having to learn new programs im not used to. but need to do it bad. lol

Comment: @jaredwilli - I know you hate having to learn new programs, but I'll bet you'll look back and realize you hated even worse beating your head against the wall on these kind of things when you could have been mastering them! :) If you were to quit asking questions it'll mean I get less points for me so ya gotta know I'm only trying to help! ;-)

Comment: @MikeSchinkel In case you wanted to try out the remove thing, I updated the gist I made with the working jQuery code. I didn't change the post type to post though, so just change it from 'product' to 'post' if you try it again.
https://gist.github.com/802465

Comment: @MikeSchinkel Yes, I would then become more of a threat to your points ;)
I do and have known that i do need to be more unit testing and debuggy while i code. So yeah,

Comment: @jaredwilli - Cool, but I think I've gonna call it a weekend. Glad I could help. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

if i understand you question you need to get the list of sizes first like this:

```
$image_sizes = get_intermediate_image_sizes();
```

this returns an array of all image sizes registered (defaults: large, medium, thumbnail , any custom size registered using "add_image_size()"
then all you have to do is loop trough each one of the sizes and create an image for that size like this:

```
$foreach ($image_sizes as $size){
    images[] = image_make_intermediate_size($file, $size['width'], $size['height'], $crop); 
}
```

replace $file with the uploaded file path and $crop with true or false if you want to crop the image to the new dimensions or false to resize.

Comment: @בניית אתרים - If you take a look at the code for `wp_generate_attachment_metadata()` in `/wp-admin/includes/image.php` you will see it does exactly what you posted above, and he is already called that. So if those are not being created then maybe he's got a plugin that filters them using the `'intermediate_image_sizes_advanced'` hook?

Comment: I actually hadnt tried using get_intermediate_image_sizes(); I wasn't aware that it got all the registered sizes. Which is nice to know now. I still don't quite understand how the generated image sizes are associated with a particular attachment though, like if i were to look in the media library, you see the 3 size options, when selecting one of those, it knows which image to grab. Idk, that's not as important. Unless it is. After doing that foreach loop what variable would i use to add the attachment though? $images['thumb'] or something (whatever size i want)?

Comment: @בניית אתרים - Both of us missed the real problem at first. The real problem was about about 7 or 8 code errors in the original example. See my updated answer.

Comment: Yea it was late here and i was brain dead.

Comment: @בניית אתרים - Same. :)