# Only create image size when used in featured image

Tags: post-thumbnails, images

I'm using a post thumbnail size and I was wondering if there is a way to setup so wordpress only make the thumbnail size when the image I upload is used as the featured image rather than for every image on the site.

```
// add Thumbnail option
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails', array('post', 'svg'));
set_post_thumbnail_size(275, 154, true);
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is possible as WP creates different sizes of the images on uploading it through the media uploader. Using/not using it as a featured image comes pretty  much after that

Comment: There is an accepted answer to a similar question here: [https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/57374/92868](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/57374/92868)

Answer (score 0):

There is such plugin: [Dynamic Image Resizer](http://wordpress.org/plugins/dynamic-image-resizer/) so you could give it a try. But... it's old, not maintained since 2012-04-30 so I'm not sure if it still works.

> Normally when you upload an image to a WordPress site, it creates
>   several differently sized versions of the image automatically. Themes
>   can define custom image sizes as well, increasing the amount of images
>   generated on your server.
>
> This plugin changes the way WordPress creates images to make it
>   generate the images only when they are actually used somewhere, on the
>   fly. Images created thusly will be saved in the normal upload
>   directories, for later fast sending by the webserver. The result is
>   that space is saved (since images are only created when needed), and
>   uploading images is much faster (since it's not generating the images
>   on upload anymore).
>
> "Pretty" permalinks must be enabled for this plugin to function.
>
> Note: This plugin does not work on multisite setups, due to the way
>   WordPress handles file serving in such situations (with ms-files.php).