# Custom Woocommerce image size

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Woocommerce has three built in image sizes. But since there are more than three different container sizes, some images always get stretched or squeezed. Hence image quality and page speed suffer. Woocommerce uses for example the catalogue size for catalogue images and related product images. Wordpress offers an easy method to generate custom image sizes. And i've tried to generate a size for my related products:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'jmt_theme_setup' );
function jmt_theme_setup() {
add_image_size( 'related-thumb', 274, 274, true );
}
```

Is there a way to plug this size into woocommerce related product images?

Thanks for your interest.

regards
theo

Comment: The real issue lies with the WooCommerce CSS. I believe they have all their images `width: 100%; height: auto;` which some themes don't take into account. I suggest overwriting that css with `max-width: 100%; width: auto;` instead.

Comment: Yes, i can confirm. Max-width:100%; reduces the related product image container to the size of the catalogue image container. But it also changes the lay-out. My goal or rather my idea is to customize the image size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few options you can choose from whenever changing image sizes. Switching out the actual default WooCommerce images is more difficult than a normal WordPress install as they are ingrained with the plugin.

---

**Modify Related Product Image Sizes:**

I've tested this and it seems to work only on related products ( though I'm sure it could be expanded to other areas ). You may still need to take advantage of [Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) to get the correct sizes.

We need to put everything into a `wp` filter:

```
function woo_init() {
    // Below functions go here...
}
add_action( 'wp', 'woo_init' );
```

I was able to skip the first portion of this, setting the query var and still have it work but since it uses a generic `content-product.php` template I wouldn't trust it, so we will set a query var ensuring we are only change the image size for related products:

```
if( is_singular( 'product' ) ) {
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_related_products_args', function( $query_args ) {
        if( ! empty( $query_args ) ) {
            set_query_var( 'related_products', true );
        }

        return $query_args;
    } );
}
```

Next we need to remove the default `loop_product_thumbnail` and replace it with our custom one. We test to ensure `realted_products` queryvar is set and `TRUE` before we serve our new image, otherwise serve the default image.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title',
    function() {
        $related = get_query_var( 'related_products' );
        if( TRUE == $related ) {
            echo woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail( 'related-thumb', 274, 274 );    // Our new image size
        } else {
            echo woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail();   // Default Image Size
        }
    },
    10
);
```

---

**CSS**

WooCommerce uses `width: 100%; height: auto;` on *all* their images. You could change this to `max-width: 100%; width: auto; height: auto;` and play around with the margins / number of columns to get the desired look.

**Change the initial image sizes**

You can change the actual image sizes WooCommerce uses by following the steps below:

- Log into WordPress
- Navigate to `WooCommerce -> Products Tab -> Display ( Sub-tab )`
- Toward the bottom you can set the image sizes for:

  - Catalog Images
  - Single Product Image
  - Product Thumbnails
- Finally, you can install [Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) to get the changed sizes.

---

Another method is to have these sizes on install:

```
function yourtheme_woocommerce_image_dimensions() {
    global $pagenow;

    if ( ! isset( $_GET['activated'] ) || $pagenow != 'themes.php' ) {
        return;
    }

    $catalog = array(
        'width'     => '400',   // px
        'height'    => '400',   // px
        'crop'      => 1        // true
    );

    $single = array(
        'width'     => '600',   // px
        'height'    => '600',   // px
        'crop'      => 1        // true
    );

    $thumbnail = array(
        'width'     => '120',   // px
        'height'    => '120',   // px
        'crop'      => 0        // false
    );

    // Image sizes
    update_option( 'shop_catalog_image_size', $catalog );       // Product category thumbs
    update_option( 'shop_single_image_size', $single );         // Single product image
    update_option( 'shop_thumbnail_image_size', $thumbnail );   // Image gallery thumbs
}

add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'yourtheme_woocommerce_image_dimensions', 1 );
```

WooCommerce Reference Links:

- [Using appropriate image dimensions to avoid distortion / pixellation](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/using-the-appropriate-product-image-dimensions/)
- [Set WooCommerce image dimensions upon theme activation](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/set-woocommerce-image-dimensions-upon-theme-activation/)
- [`woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail` Function](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/function-woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail.html)

Comment: Thank you. I've tried all that. But apparently the only solution is to compromise. That means one size for related and catalogue images. I was just wondering, if there was an easy way to add a fourth image dimension. regards theo

Comment: @theo - Unfortunately, not that I'm aware of. Theoretically, you could override the [WooCommerce Template](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/) with your own, create your own [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and generate the same loop but call your custom image that way. There *could* be another way I've never tried but I'll edit my question with it and maybe you could have some luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. I'll try it and will let you know.

Comment: Ok, i tried and failed. I guess i'll have to settle with this limitation. But thanks for all the hints.

Comment: @timholz I don't have an active woocommerce install to play around with this. Whenever I get a chance I'll give it a try and see what I come up with. If I find something out I'll tag you and let you know or if you find a better solution post it here! Good luck!

Comment: Hi Howdy Mc Gee, thanks for your response. For the time being i assigned the largest dimension for related and catalogue images. Looks ok, but looses a little speed, since catalogue images have to be scaled down. But anyway, thanks for your care.:)theo

Comment: @timholz I found a solution which I've modified my answer and prepended the solution. I took the original theory and tested it, should work for related products and you could probably make it work for other products too. If you found that it worked for you, don't forget to click the checkmark to show future readers that it worked for you!

Comment: – Thanks for your effort. It's too late now. But tomorrow i'll test the code and will report.

Comment: Hi Howdy McGee – i couldn't wait till tomorrow. Your code works great. It's the conditional that does the magic. Thank you very much for your time and effort. The site i am working on is in developement mode, but as soon as it's ready i'll send you a link. (just in case you are interested). Thank you ver much. regards theo p.s.: i tried to vote you up, but alas, my reputation is insufficient. So, i'll vote you up here. Top level answer.

Comment: @timholz I'm glad that worked for you! Please make sure to click the checkmark so future readers know that this answered your question ( comments are hidden after so many ). I would also suggest going back to any other questions you've asked in the past and doing the same ( even if you answered them ). It's a great and easy way to earn rep along with show your thanks!

Comment: this is the link:[www.j-m-t.ch](http://www.j-m-t.ch) Now i have the appropriate image-sizes for catalogue- and related-products. thank you

Comment: there is one thing i noticed. Featured products (when layout is set to full width) are of course fetching the catalogue size and are therefor blurry. I tried adapting the same method for this class but apparently they are treated differently.

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite the CSS of WooCommerce through this snippet, [Remi Corson](http://www.remicorson.com/woocommerce-change-related-products-image-size/):

```
<?php
add_filter( 'wp_head' , 'related_products_style' );

function related_products_style() {
   if( is_product() ) :
   ?>
   <style>
   .woocommerce .related ul.products li.product img, .woocommerce .related ul li.product img, .woocommerce .upsells.products ul.products li.product img, .woocommerce .upsells.products ul li.product img, .woocommerce-page .related ul.products li.product img, .woocommerce-page .related ul li.product img, .woocommerce-page .upsells.products ul.products li.product img, .woocommerce-page .upsells.products ul li.product img
   {
      width: 274px !important;
      height: 274px !important;
   }
   </style>
<?php
endif;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but overwriting the css does not apply the correct image sizes. It sets the container size.

Comment: I have appended `img` to the CSS rules, can you try now?

Comment: Thanks for the update. But no, now the proportions are no longer square and the css is only affecting the container. What i tried to achieve is to plug in the appropriate image size. But this is, as i now learn rather difficult to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a CSS problem because WooCommerce (annoyingly) uses `width: 100%` when it (in my opinion) should be `max-width: 100%`. Try to overwrite the width using `width: auto`, that should help.